# Ion library null pointer exception while getting array as result from server

Tags: android, realm, android-ion

I am using ion library for getting data from server and storing that data in Ralm.

```
    final Context context = view.getContext();
    Ion.with(context)
            .load(TeamConstants.TEAM_URL + "team-masters")
            .asJsonArray()
            .setCallback(new FutureCallback<JsonArray>() {

                public void onCompleted(Exception e, JsonArray result) {
                    //TODO update realm data for updateTeam
                    Toast.makeText(context, " success !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    try {
                        if (e == null) {
                            gameRealm =
                                    Realm.getInstance(
                                            new RealmConfiguration.Builder(context)
                                                    .name("AllTeams.realm")
                                                    .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                                                    .build()
                                    );
                            gameRealm.beginTransaction();

                            for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {
                                AllTeamData coachTeamsData = new AllTeamData();
                                coachTeamsData.setTeamId(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("id").getAsInt());
                                coachTeamsData.setTeamLocation(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("location").getAsString());
                                coachTeamsData.setTeamName(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("name").getAsString());
                                coachTeamsData.setCoachId(result.get(i).getAsJsonObject().get("coach_id").getAsInt());
                            }


                        }
                    } catch (Exception ex) {
                        Util.Log("Exception",ex.getMessage());
                    }

                }
            });

    resultTeamNames = gameRealm.where(CoachTeamsData.class).findAll();
```

---

```
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at org.openinfotech.teammanagement.teams.AllTeamsFragment.onCreateView(AllTeamsFragment.java:97)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1974)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1252)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:742)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1617)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentStatePagerAdapter.java:164)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1177)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1025)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1545)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout.onMeasure(DrawerLayout.java:1075)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1404)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:695)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:588)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5286)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2421)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16677)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1927)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1119)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1301)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1006)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5652)
06-22 12:11:17.171 17770-17770/org.openinfotech.teammanagement E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
```

Comment: Please update the code snippet. `gameRealm` in the last line seems to be out of scope, and I can't see any `commitTransaction()`.

Comment: that would be a solid candidate for the NPE since `gameRealm` is null at the moment it's called right now

Comment: thanks everyone.. i have solved it..